# PNG True color with Alpha decoding

Tags: java, png

I am writing a PNG decoder and I am encountering some weirdness. Going through the PNG file format, I have managed to decode PNGs with Color Index + tRNS (alpha) and True Color + tRNS (alpha) correctly. I am currently not sure why I cannot decode a PNG with True Color with Alpha type PNG. I have verified that my inflate of IDAT chunk is correct. Here's what the chunks looks like:

```
Width: 256
Height: 256
Bit Depth: 8
Color Type: 6
Compression: 0
Filter: 0
Interlace: 0

Length: 25
Type: tEXt
Data: 53 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65 00 41 64 6f 62 65 20 49 6d 61 67 65 52 65 61 64 79 
CRC: 71c9653c

Length: 20690
Type: IDAT
Data: 78 da ec 7d 09 9c 1c 57 99 df f7 7a a6 e7 3e 5a a3 fb ...
CRC: 21550259
```

The actual data is too long to be printed here. Here's my logic of decoding this, please correct me if I'm wrong:

1. Inflate all the bytes given in the IDAT chunk
2. Un-filter the inflated chunks. In this case, all filters are of type 0 and therefore, we simply discard the filter byte.
3. Since this is color type 6, a pixel is represented by RGBA channels with 1 byte each. This means we need to interpret 4 bytes at a time. The following code is used:

   ```
   ByteBuffer image = BufferUtil.getDirectByteBuffer(data.length, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
   int i = 0;
   while(i < data.length){
   int color = ( (data[i] & 0xff) << 24) | ( (data[i+1] & 0xff) << 16) | ( (data[i+2] & 0xff) << 8) | (data[i+3] & 0xff);
   image.putInt(color);
   i += 4;
   ```

What's strange is that I get mostly RRGGBBAA = 0x00000000 data resulting in a clear image with little color.

[image: Decoded Image]

[image: Original Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are neglecting to observe the filtering for each scanline.

From the image provided the decompressed data looks like

1   ffffffff    0   0   0   ...
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...
..

the first value in each line conforms to the filter method used [[http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#9Filters]](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#9Filters%5d)

the scanlines post processing will look like

ffffffff    ffffffff    ffffffff ...
ffffffff    ffffffff    ffffffff ...
...

here is some example code that handles methods 0, 1 and 2.

```
private static void processScanLine(byte filterValue, byte[] scanLine, byte[] previousScanLine) {
    switch(filterValue){
        case 0:break;
        case 1:
            for (int i =4;i<scanLine.length;i++){
                scanLine[i] = (byte)(scanLine[i]+scanLine[i-4]);
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            for (int i =0;i<scanLine.length;i++){
                scanLine[i] = (byte)(scanLine[i]+previousScanLine[i]);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you decompress the short sample snippet of compressed data? The OP asserted that "all filters are of type 0".

Comment: Here's the binary data before it's de-compressed:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/20j10fuburid4sy/pre_inflate_data.dat

Here's the binary data that's after it's de-compressed:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x35k5df3rpx0tqi/post_inflate_data.dat

Here are some samples after it's de-compression:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ...

So it would appear that the filtering byte is 0x0.

Comment: It appears that after a first few scanlines, filter code can be non-zero. Sorry for the fuss.

Comment: What's the difference between previous scan-line and the scan-line immediately before the current one?

Comment: I used the image posted for testing the code. Assumed that was the one being displayed.

Comment: scanline is the the line currently being processed. previousScanline should be the line immediately above it. So if scan line 5 is being processed then previousScaneline should be line 4.

Comment: OP likes to make things tough :) The decompressed data doesn't look *anything* like the sample image. The reason it starts with loads of zeroes is, well, because the *image* starts with loads of blank lines. And indeed, "all filters are of type 0" is simply not true.